# shortcuts mac osx

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to make shortcuts work like in mac os x system wide?

Would increase user base if user could stick to their accustomed way of working.

Elementary teaks is letting me change window layout to osx. Would be great to have something similar for shortcut behavior?

Have been looking for something like this for a whole day without end. Under system settings-> keyboard I can change the keys, but then it conflicts with browser behavior of Epiphany where super+t should open new tab, but Ctrl+t does.

Maybe best would be, to make a decision at set up or at sign in, where it asks me if I want to have a similar behavior than Mac os x or Windows?

Comment: This is the dream :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to `System Settings`and choose `Keyboard`.
You'll there all keyboards that you have.

Click the + to add new keyboard.
Choose language (I checked it for `English US` and `English UK`, so I think that there may be a problem with some other languages, but you need to check it out)
Choose layout `English(Macintosh)`.
Add it and set as your primary keyboard.

Now you should have your keyboard layout set to the same as Apple offers. :)

Comment: Was not asking about LAYOUT, was asking about SHORTCUTS. So you answer the wrong question. If you can please delete your answer, cause it might confuse others. Thanks